# On IE 8, 9, and 10, is document an instance of which class?

Tags: javascript, dom

On Chrome and Firefox's console, I am able to do

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document) === HTMLDocument.prototype
```

and get a `true`, meaning that `document` is an instance of the `HTMLDocument` class.  But on IE 8, 9, or 10, I will get an error for `HTMLDocument is undefined`.

So on IE 8, 9, and 10, is `document` an instance of which class?

(On IE 11 Preview, it works... it is a bit strange that IE 10, being so modern, doesn't have the standard of `HTMLDocument` defined).

A side note: I see something strange for a pattern not being followed on IE:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document)  // => [object DocumentPrototype] { ... }
```

and

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document) === Document.prototype  // => false
```

but

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document.body)  // => [object HTMLBodyElementPrototype] { ... }
```

and

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document.body) === HTMLBodyElement.prototype  // => true
```

Comment: You seem to be asking the eternal question, "Why don't all browsers implement host objects the same way?". **EDIT** `document.constructor` is `HTMLDocument` in most browsers, `Document` in IE<=10, not sure about IE11, `document instanceof Document` is `true`

Comment: not all browsers have to implement them the same way, but I am just asking, what class is `document` an instance of, if I have to write the line `if (Object.getPrototypeOf(document) === Foo.prototype)`, what should `Foo` be?

Comment: @動靜能量 why would you ever have to write that?

Comment: I write that to confirm my knowledge of the DOM and to test it on common modern browsers

Comment: HTMLDocument prior to version 11.Wait for 11 to release or try Preview for just test :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking the eternal question, "Why don't all browsers implement host objects the same way?".

To answer your question about `document`, let's look at `document.constructor`

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document) === document.constructor.prototype; // true
```

So, what is `document.constructor` in IE?

```
document.constructor === Document; // true in IE 10, 9
// hence
Object.getPrototypeOf(document) === Document.prototype; // true in IE 10, 9
```

You'll notice IE8 does not support `Object.getPrototypeOf` or have `Document`, however it does have `HTMLDocument`

Further note that across all main browsers (excluding IE8)

```
document instanceof Document; // true
```

Therefore, you can use `Document.prototype` for all browsers, though I wouldn't really advise it because you may break other code / forward compatibility

```
Document.prototype.foo = 'bar';
document.foo; // "bar"
```

Comment: It is strange that in the jsfiddle.net, in the console of IE 10, if I do `Object.getPrototypeOf(document) === Document.prototype` it is `false`, but if I go to google.com or bing.com and run that line again, it is `true`

Comment: it is not an "eternal question".  The DOM tends to be quite standard across all modern browsers, especially if we are talking about Chrome and IE 10 that is just released so recently.